# Does topologically conjugate means stability property also same ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If two flows are topologically conjugate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy), then if $x^*$ is an asymptotically stable point in one flow, will it be the same in another flow also. I don't think so.

Comment: Indeed, although it is clearly the case in dimension $1$.